# Machine Learning Algorithm for Minimizing Simulation Error

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, simulation

I have a set of simulation output that has an error value associated with each trial, along with the parameters that were used. In practice, some of these parameters will be fixed by the environment while the rest can be chosen.  These parameters are all continuous, and most have nonlinear relationships with the error. What techniques might be useful in selecting the values for the changeable parameters given the fixed parameters in order to minimize error? I am having trouble finding an approach that seems appropriate. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For each combination of continuously adjustable parameters, can you conduct multiple simulation trials, each of which results in a sample error? And you want to find the (optimal) values of those parameters which minimize some (loss) function of the errors?  That is a simulation optimization problem.  Can you use common random numbers to simulate across different parameter settings?  Is the output error a continuous function of parameters on a per simulation trial basis? Can you "differentiate" the simulation program w/ respect to the parameters? How long does each simulation replication take?

Comment: Yes and Yes to the first two. I'm not sure what you mean by "common" random numbers, but I suspect yes. I also don't know what you mean by continuity. Every simulation gives a sample error as output (mean error for these parameters plus noise), and the relationship between the parameters and the underlying error appears continuous-ish but I highly doubt it's continuous in a strict sense given the underlying discrete process I'm modeling. Simulations take a few seconds each.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: There is a certain discrete process I'm trying to simulate that involves a lot of randomness. With any given set of parameters, there are a wide range of possible outcomes. Each outcome has an error measure I've assigned to it, and for any given set of parameters there should be an average error. It seems that when I increase or decrease these parameters the average error changes in a roughly smooth though nonlinear (quadratic?) way, though given the nature of the underlying process its likely only approximately continuous, more of a step function. Does that help or do you need more specifics?

Comment: Need more specifics. It may be that your objective function (what you are trying to find the minimal value of) is continuous. Objective function is the expected value of some function of the output of the simulation. That doesn't mean the function whose expected value you are minimizing is a continuous function of the parameters for any one trial of the simulation - i.e., using same random number draws, but changing the parameter value. That's relevant to what technique(s) can be used to estimate derivatives (gradient) of objective function. How many parameters? Any constraints on parametewrs?

Comment: If you can just spell out the whole problem in detail, please do so.

Comment: Spelling the whole problem out in detail would be pretty impossible in this kind of forum as it's a fairly complex system I'm trying to simulate. There are any number of problems that might fit what I've outlined so far, and an applicable method to that general kind of problem would be an acceptable answer. It's fairly few parameters, less than 10. Most of them are positive, and all realistic values are small enough that generating enough simulation data capturing all the interactions is not a concern, it's just how to process it. Assuming it is continuous, as i suspect, then what?

Comment: If you can directly simulate the gradient, you probably should use a gradient-based optimization method. If not, then a derivative-free method, But you havem't given enough information to know whether/how gradient could be simulated. Any generic guidance you get won't be very good, even though you might be offered some. Read this to get some ideas http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781493913831 but there are better, but not widely available methods. This is a tricky area of optimization. If you have an interesting enough problem, I might be willing to solve it for you as a test problem for me.